# How to place wide <table> in MVC3/Razor within a scrollable area?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a wide HTML table to display in MVC3/Razor and I need to put it in a scrollable container or some type of paging control.

The data columns will contain `mo-yyyy` data that is up to two years so 24 columns wide.

Is there a better way to do this than HTML `<table>`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would specify scrolling in the site.css

```
.data_table
{
   overflow-x:  auto;
}
```

Controls do not exist in MVC. You need to work with partial views and template for displaying and editing data. You could write a partial view that would contain your data table. You could then write another partial view that would contain your paging feature.

To do this you will probably require two view models to support your partial views: one for data table and one for paging information. You could then base your views on these view models.